# Adding a new hard drive to xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, intranet

I am running xampp as an intranet server using 'virtualhost' for 15 'sites' inside our network and things are working fine with 3 exceptions.  First problem is my biggest-my 2TB drive is full and I need to add another drive to the server to call up data - how can I do this?

Here are 2 virtual domains from the vhosts file - the 3rd example is what i need to accomplish.

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.106.162:80>
    ServerName clubcal.iserver
    ServerAlias www.clubcal.iserver
    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/clubcal"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.16.106.163:80>
    ServerName digiport.iserver
    ServerAlias www.digiport.iserver
    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/digiport"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is an example of what I need to do:

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.106.164:80>
    ServerName tzone.iserver
    ServerAlias www.tzone.iserver
    DocumentRoot "G:/public_html/tzone"
</VirtualHost>
```

This xampp server is a separate Windows7 (64bit) system in our network with windows Active Directory resolving DNS issues inside our VLAN (I will downgrade it to 32bit this weekend).

My hosts file resolves ip#'s to domain names in the server, the NIC is assigned with multiple IP #'s so it does work everywhere on our VLAN.

Any insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort of "span" the drive, Windows has this handy feature (similar to linux's symlinking) called [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which you can create a folder in the current directory that is just a symbolic link to the drive. Quick and easy way to span it. I am not sure of any downsides to do doing this, other than if the drive letter changes (if external drive).

That way you should not have to add or change any of your paths in the config etc. Not sure if that is what you were looking for, but hopefully it helps.

Also, did you try your 3rd config you pasted? Did it not work? From what I can see, as long as permissions are fine it should work that way.

Comment: I thought it should work that way also but all I get is a 403 error.  Very frustrating...

Comment: The only thing that stands out are permissions. I am not sure why that would matter too much (unless xampp runs as it's own windows account). I would check that whatever windows account xampp is running as, has access to that drive / folder(s).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an issue with permissions in the network?
Not sure if it makes a difference, but maybe worth trying to add this to your 3d cfg:

```
<Directory "G:/public_html/tzone">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I did try that before and I also copy paste yours in all still get a 403 error.  Not sure how it could be network permissions...  I get 403 from LAN machine and as localhost on this server.   I should mention, this operation is on a barebones test system running Win7Pro 32bit, I am not testing on the production unit until I can get it running in 2 test units.